# Password Generation in java with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

IDFC, a leading Bank sector offers online shopping to their customers, To avail this offer, the customer will have to generate a security code, for the first time usage of his card to purchase online.

Hint to generate a security code is as follows :

1.Minimum of 8 Characters

2.Must contain atleast one uppercase, one lowercase and one special character.

3. Only the special characters @,*,#  are allowed.

The code fails to meet the criteria, will response with an error message as shown in the sample output.

Develop an application to implement this scenario.

Write a public class Main with the main method.  Write the code to get the input, validate and print the output.

**Sample Input 1:**

Generate your Security Code

Ab12345@

**Sample Output 1:**

Security Code Generated Successfully

**Sample Input 2:**

Generate your Security Code

S1995p123

**Sample Output 2:**

Invalid Security Code, Try Again!

**I was able to come up with a code which basically passes all the visible condition, but failing to test one. Not really sure where I am going wrong.**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main{
        public static void main(String a[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Generate your Security Code");
        String code = sc.next();
        String regex = "[A-Za-z0-9@*#]{8}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
        boolean matchFound = m.find();
        if(matchFound)
        System.out.println("Security Code Generated Successfully");
        else
        System.out.println("Invalid Security Code, Try Again!");
    }
}
```

```
Evaluation Result:
Proposed grade: 75 / 100
Result Description
Failed tests
Test 3: Invalid Password

Test 1: Valid Password

Summary of tests
 
*Note: All the test cases might not have same weightage
 
4 tests run/ 3 tests passed
```

Comment: You should probably say what you did to try to fix your answer. For example, did you try the sample inputs? In your case you have a regexp that accepts the right characters but doesn't test any of the other requirements (at least one cap, at least one lower case, at least one special character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it says that it has a minimum of 8 characters you must use `{8,}` this means 8 or more characters.

with your current regex, `ab12345@` is accepted and as you can see there is no upper case character so a better regex would be:

`^(?=.*[@*#])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9@*#]{8,}$`

Comment: I would add an anchor `^` at the start of the pattern, or else when there is no match, the lookahead will still be tried at every position.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for saying it, I edited my answer.